# How to edit an image in elementor within Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, elementor

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoF4Z.jpg)

I want to move an image center of the green circle
Image is a overlap of 2 elements as you can see in image

I'm working on a template, so i dont have knowledge on elementor

I tried to drag the image, but whenever i tried to move image, it only goes down and down.

Comment: If I lack on details, pls let me know can I contact you for clarify my doubt